# Why is Google Analytics Reporting Real Time Events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm not seeing any events in GA Realtime reporting after implementing below code for GA Event tracking... Standard Pageviews reporting has been working fine for since I implemented last month, the issue is just with "Events".

I tried to follow the instructions per https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview.

This is a screenshot of my Chrome Dev Tools Console 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/euamp6bz87qh6g9/Screenshot%202016-06-04%2018.33.19.png?dl=0

This is a screenshot of my Chrome Dev Tools Network: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/71lqmv492pquk1x/Screenshot%202016-06-04%2018.31.56.png?dl=0

Script in HTML before end tag  with my UA number here noted as Xs/Y - i am using a server side     with this code for each page:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->

<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview', 'event');
</script>

<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'>
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->

<!-- HTML Code -->
<ul>
<li><a href="http://iprobesolutions.com/downloads/ae-specs-en-us-bosch-dicentis-wireless.docx" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click', ‘Download DICENTIS Wireless A &amp; E');">Download DICENTIS Wireless A &amp; E Specifications</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any feedback on what I could be doing wrong would be much appreciated!

This is my edited and now working code based on feedback received:

```
 <!-- HTML Code -->
<ul>
<li><a href="http://iprobesolutions.com/downloads/ae-specs-en-us-bosch-dicentis-wireless.docx" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click', 'Download DICENTIS Wireless A &amp; E');">Download DICENTIS Wireless A &amp; E Specifications</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When did you implemented this feature?

Comment: GA pageviews a few weeks ago but Events about an hour before I posted. I tried with the hit builder per https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ and I had some success initially with seeing those hits on Realtime Events but I don't really understand how to use Hit Builder within my actual code and what the advantage would be using Hit Builder as compared to my current approach.

Comment: Everytime I ran problems with GA codes, time was my answer. Maybe you should wait more?

Comment: LOL sure tx...I'll give it a few days..plenty of other issues to tackle beyond this one anyway! I'll ping back if it's still not working in a week or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing pageviews and not events, then it's not really a matter time and waiting for the events to be processed, but probably something to do with your code or implementation. I am seeing a potential issue with the onclick code, however:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click', ‘Download DICENTIS Wireless A &amp; E');
```

Your event label is using a smart quote rather than a straight quote. When I paste the event code into the console, I get an error message, so you should change the `‘` to a `'` and make sure they are all straight quotes.

Also, when you are sending your pageview with `ga('send', 'pageview', 'event')`, I'm not sure if you are aware, but you are changing the page path from the default of whatever is normally sent with the pageview, to `event`. So in your reports, you would see a page path for your pageviews of `event`.

Comment: From my brief JS training a few years back I seem to remember you can either use single quotes (straight) or double quotes. Would this double quote work too " ? Because my line of work uses smart "curly" quotes it's  a hassle to change my windows preferences so if below is acceptable it would be easier for me: ga("send", "event", "download", "click", "Download DICENTIS Wireless A &amp; E'"); let me know pls?

Comment: Double quotes works as well, so long as you're consistent and they match up. But in the line that you have, you've got a single and double at the end which would throw an error i think.

Comment: Yes I now understand!..you meant the quote before "Download" needed to change from curly quote to straight quote. It's working now! I updated my code in the question. Thank you Nyuen!